# No release file for opensuse website when I run "sudo apt update"

Tags: apt, updates

Here's what I get when I run `sudo apt update`:

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                                
Hit:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                       
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                             
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/notepadqq-team/notepadqq/ubuntu xenial InRelease                           
Ign:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/netvirt/xUbuntu_14.10 ./ InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/haguichi/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/netvirt/xUbuntu_14.10 ./ Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:2178:8::13 80]
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/netvirt/xUbuntu_14.10 ./ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How do I either fix or remove this repository?

Comment: You see this because the repository is removed. Time to clear your source.list file

Comment: @Anwar Disabling all OpenSuse sources in my "Other Software" menu worked, thanks.